# spaCy displacy output using anvil.works server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy, displacy

I am attempting to display entities using spaCy's displacy feature.
The output of my render is being shown in my Jupyter Notebook code cell with my `anvil.server.wait_forever()` code.

[Here is an example of the code cell output I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqkGB.jpg)

[I would rather have the output appear here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjcHE.jpg)

I have already tried using displacy.server instead of displacy.render and tried auto_port.

Here is my code:

```
def visualize_entities_in_sentences(self, doc_id):
    """Visualize entities in the sentences of a document.

    :param doc_id: the id of the document to visualize
    :type doc_id: str
    """
    doc = self.get_document(doc_id)
    sentences = list(doc.sents)
    labels = displacy.render(sentences, style="ent", page=False, minify=True)
    return labels
```

And my callable for the Anvil implementation:

```py
@anvil.server.callable
def get_visualize_entities_in_sentences(doc_id):
    """"Get the document markdown for a document in my_corpus with entity labels visualized.

    :param doc_id: a document id
    :type doc_id: str
    :returns: markdown
    :rtype: str
    """    
    return my_corpus.visualize_entities_in_sentences(doc_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `jupyter=False` to `displacy.render` to skip the jupyter auto-detection.

Comment: Progress! Thank you! Unfortunately though, the output is now printed HTML, but in the right location.

Here is a [Photo example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK7KT.jpg)

Thanks again for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `jupyter=False` in my server-side `displacy.render` code *and* changing my Anvil server markdown box to HTML format within the client worked.